# How to use Django with Azure's CosmosDB?

Tags: django, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm curious if it is possible to use CosmosDB as the database backend for Django projects.

Comment: CosmosDB is a multi-model database which includes DocumentDB API, MongoDB API, Graph API and Table API. But your description is not clear for which service you want to use as database backend for Django. Could you update more details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a fork that supports MongoDB as a Django database:

https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine

You just need to select the MongoDB Api in your Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: This project seems dead.

Comment: it wasn't when I provided the answer three years ago

Answer (score 4):

mongodb-engine seems dead, but I found djongo, which seems to be active:

https://github.com/nesdis/djongo

It's a connector that lets you use Django with MongoDB without changing the Django ORM.

You would need to configure your Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB.

Comment: How should settings be set for azure cosmos and djoser?

Comment: I don't know what djoser is, but you'd need to find the connection settings in Azure Cosmos DB and use those in your Django settings file.

Comment: I meant Azure and Djongo. Sorry. And I managed to get it working so thanks.